# css different size boxes allign to eachother

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to make a layout out of boxes.

[image: see image for clear view]

the problem is that my second row will go under my larger box, I'm trying to make it so when my site shrinks in width the last box will wrap to the left. the order of the images doesn't really matter.
I hope this is possible in any way. I'm not that advanced on HTML and CSS I'm just trying to make an interesting site for my portfolio.

thanks for reading

Comment: Try flexbox more detail explanation on this site https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You'd better try masonry layout.  For example, this javascript plugin: https://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with the `column-count` property on the parent and `media` queries:

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%}

.parent {
  column-count: 4; /* four images per row when full screen */
  column-gap: 10px; /* for horizontal gaps between img's */
}

.parent > img { /* responsiveness */
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* vertical gap */
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .parent {
    column-count: 3; /* three images per row */
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .parent {
    column-count: 2; /* two images per row */
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .parent {
    column-count: 1; /* one image per row */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/b9lb-T9FrAg/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn.thinglink.me/api/image/703615529729916929/1240/10/scaletowidth" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn.akc.org/Marketplace/Breeds/Siberian_Husky_SERP.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/2709324/images/o-BULLDOG-PUPPY-facebook.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/2709324/images/o-BULLDOG-PUPPY-facebook.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn.akc.org/Marketplace/Breeds/Siberian_Husky_SERP.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn.thinglink.me/api/image/703615529729916929/1240/10/scaletowidth" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/b9lb-T9FrAg/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/b9lb-T9FrAg/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn.thinglink.me/api/image/703615529729916929/1240/10/scaletowidth" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn.akc.org/Marketplace/Breeds/Siberian_Husky_SERP.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/2709324/images/o-BULLDOG-PUPPY-facebook.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `flex` like this :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.container img {
  width: 33%;
  border:2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/" />
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/400/" />
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/" />
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/100/" />
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/500/200/" />
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/400/" />
</div>
```

Then you have to adjust the value i specified depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This code might solve your problem.
        --CSS--

```css
.slidepanels {
  /* Prevent vertical gaps */
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 8px;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-gap: 8px;
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 8px;
}

.cycler {
  position: relative;
}

.cycler img:first-child {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cycler img:not(:first-child) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.cycler img.active {
  z-index: 3;
}

.slidepanels div img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  margin-bottom: 3.6%;
}

@media (max-width: 620px) {
  .slidepanels {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .slidepanels {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slidepanels">
  <div id="cycler1" class="cycler">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/d5/c4/37/d5c43719a8e57e08046258f3551ab5bd.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="cycler1" class="cycler">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/b4/e2/6e/b4e26e25176a8bf4c5307645ef45f745.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="cycler1" class="cycler">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/88/fb/b1/88fbb1d82e00027dcf3a42bfbd5bbdda.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="cycler1" class="cycler">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/ed/2a/94/ed2a949af7ad6ceb70115c4ba0a4c1b6.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="cycler1" class="cycler">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/d5/c4/37/d5c43719a8e57e08046258f3551ab5bd.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="cycler1" class="cycler">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/b4/e2/6e/b4e26e25176a8bf4c5307645ef45f745.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="cycler1" class="cycler">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/88/fb/b1/88fbb1d82e00027dcf3a42bfbd5bbdda.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="cycler1" class="cycler">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/ed/2a/94/ed2a949af7ad6ceb70115c4ba0a4c1b6.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should give a link to column css and an explanation and use images of different heights ;)